# How to select date from drop down menu using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium

I have a date picker where I can select a date range like 3months, 7 days or this year.
How can I select "This year" from a drop down menu?

Here is the code:

```
 <div class="full">
   <div class="range-preset">
    <div class="date-range-selector">
    <label>Date Range:</label>
    <select class="full" style="width:230px; ">
    <option value="custom">Custom</option>
    <option value="yesterday">Yesterday</option>
    <option value="7days">7 Days</option>
    <option value="30days">30 Days</option>
    <option value="90days">90 Days</option>
    <option value="this_month">This Month</option>
    <option value="last_month">Last Month</option>
    <option value="two_months_ago">Two Months Ago</option>
    <option value="this_year">This Year</option>
    <option value="yesterday">Yesterday</option>
    </select>
   </div>
  </div>
```

I tried this:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("full.option.this_year")).click();
```

Any help please, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code...

```
<select id="drop_down_menu" class="range-preset">
    <option value="custom">Custom</option>
    <option value="yesterday">Yesterday</option>
    <option value="7days">7 Days</option>
    <option value="30days">30 Days</option>
    <option value="90days">90 Days</option>
    <option value="this_month">This Month</option>
    <option value="last_month">Last Month</option>
    <option value="two_months_ago">Two Months Ago</option>
    <option value="this_year">This Year</option>
    <option value="yesterday">Yesterday</option>
</select>

Select combo_box = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("drop_down_menu")));

List<WebElement> options = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("drop_down_menu"))).getOptions();
```

Comment: Your example is working if we have id but in my case i don't have id, i have class

Comment: You can add the id, you don't need to delete the class

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#user-input-filling-in-forms) page about filling forms.

Generally, to deal with selectors you should use the Select class. Below is an example:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.className("full")));
select.deselectAll();
select.selectByVisibleText("Edam");
```

Then you will have to find and click on your "submit" button.

This is assuming you use Java. It is described in the same link how to do the same using Python.